# Localization of power series and module structure

Tags: localization, modules, nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R=\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ be the polynomial ring of two commuting variable.
Let $S$ be the multiplicative subset of $R$ generated by homogeneous linear polynomials.
Let also $\widehat{R}$ be the ring of formal power series in $X,Y,$
and $\widehat{R}_S$ be the localization of $\widehat{R}$ at $S.$
$\widehat{R}_S$ is  a $R-$module in the natural way.
Let $\widehat{R}_S^0$ be the quotient  $\widehat{R}_S/\mathbb{Q},$ all three
considered as **Abelian  groups**.

Question: Is there a $R-$module structure on $\widehat{R}_S^{0},$
which makes the quotient map a morphism of $R-$modules?

The question showed up when trying to make a distribution valued modular symbol.
The distributions map to power series via a Fourier transform.
One kills the constants as one way to make the Manin relations work.